# Spark SQL HAVING clause without Group/Aggregate

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering how the HAVING clause is working in spark sql without GroupBY or any aggregate function?

1) Can we rely on HAVING without aggregate function?
2) Is there any other way to filter the columns that are generated on that select level?

I have tried executing the below Spark SQL is it working fine but can we rely on this?

```
spark.sql("""
select 1 as a having a=1
""").show()
```

```
spark.sql("""
select 1 as a having a=2
""").show()
```

```
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|  1|
+---+

+---+
|  a|
+---+
+---+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some databases / engines, when the GROUP BY is not used in conjunction with HAVING, HAVING defaults to a WHERE clause.

Normally the WHERE clause is used.

I would not rely on HAVING without a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this: ***1) Can we rely on HAVING without aggregate function?***

No, you cannot rely on this behavior. This illegal SQL is no longer the default behavior as of Spark 2.4. But if you really want to use HAVING like  a WHERE clause you can get the old behavior by setting conf `spark.sql.legacy.parser.havingWithoutGroupByAsWhere` = `true`